# Can NHibernate QueryOver load DTO's with associations?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, .net-4.0, associations, queryover

I have an entity (A) with an association (B) and I want to load and transform all of those in DTO's (with less fields than their corresponding entities). So I want a similar structure of ADto's, each with an associated BDto. Can you do that with one query (preferably QueryOver-style)? Also it would be ideal if the BDto's are reused if the represent the same entity.

I usually do this for a single entity with `ISession.QueryOver<...>().SelectList(...);` but don't know if this works for associations as well.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this, but how did you deal with the DTOs associations?

Answer (score 0):

If you need associations in your DTOs, you have to manually provide them. Possibly this link could give you some ideas:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/generic-dto-model-and-other-silverlight.html

Basically, the idea is to have a generic wapper-model for your DTOs so you'd put both ADtos and BDtos there, however because of the way the model is created (a set of dictionaries) it's easy to cross reference dtos.

This doesn't have anything in common with NHibernate though, the idea is more general.

Comment: Certainly I can cross-reference in memory doing some coding myself. I was just looking for a "shortcut" behavior in NHibernate 3.0 that already does this.